# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/. elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

I have elastic search running on my windows machine, I can do `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/movies/_search"` and get a whole bunch of objects.

Inside angular when I try to request `var client = elasticsearch({ host: 'localhost:9200' });` with angular I get the below.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Inside `elasticsearch.yml` I have added

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

and tried with

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/"
```

Comment: What happens if you use Google Chrome to open `http://localhost:9200/movies/_search`? Look at the network tab and expand it to see the headers. Do the response headers have the expected CORS header present?

Comment: Have you tried without the double quotes? Also try to add the http scheme, too `/https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/`

Comment: @Cymen I get a json response :)

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Yes but does the HTTP headers on the response as seen in the network panel of the chrome debugger have the expected CORS header present?

Comment: Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9200
Request URL:http://localhost:9200/movies/_search
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: I dont see what the access control type looks like, but I assume its proper, where does it tell me that I am looking directly at it in the console

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry have you tried adding the http scheme to the `http.cors.allow-origin` regexp?